# ng-blur overriding $scope variable? ng-model not updating with $scope variable ionic/angular

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, blur, angular-ngmodel

I'm making a web app in ionic/angular where a user can choose a location either from a Google map that pops up in a modal, or from a Google Map autocomplete searchbox.

For the best user experience, I want the address that the user picks on the map to be entered in to the searchbox.

If I pick a location on the map first, then change the location by typing in the searchbox that works. But if I type a location in the searchbox first, then try and pick a location on the map, the text in the input box stays the same.

I think it is to do with the ionic directive you need to get the autocomplete working

```
$scope.disableTap = function(){
    container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container');
    // disable ionic data tab
    angular.element(container).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
    // leave input field if google-address-entry is selected
    angular.element(container).on("click", function(){
        document.getElementById('searchBar').blur();
    });
};
```

Here is the searchbox declaration

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchBar');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

I have an ng-model associated with the searchbox

```
<input type="text" id="searchBar" ng-focus="disableTap()" placeholder="Type address here..." 
ng-model="inputText">
```

and I am updating the $scope.inputText variable in the autocomplete listener like so:

```
$scope.inputText = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
```

and in the map listener like so:

```
$scope.inputText = address.formatted_address;
```

Does the blur function override the ng-model? Am I getting that wrong?

Can anyone see why my ng-model updates if I got map then searchbox, but not searchbox then map?

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample on plunker or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Questions of this very nature exist all over this place, and the problem described is so different each time that the site search fails.

The simple answer is, do no store values directly under $scope. This isn't about manners, but imperative once you understand the why of it. You can read up more about it at the link below.

To solve your case, you should do something like this in your controller or handlers,

```
$scope.address.formatted = ...
```

and access them like so in your views,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="..." ng-model="address.formatted" name="address.formatted">
```

To quote the relevant section from the link,

> The difference is we are not storing the data directly on the scope. Now when ng-model wants to write, it actually does a read, then write. It reads the person property from the scope, and this will work from a child scope because a child scope will search upwards for a read. Once it finds person, it writes to person.first_name, which is no problem. It just works.

And here is the link: [Nested Scopes in AngularJS on jimhoskins.com](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html)

Seeing that this is a few months old and you may've already solved it, but left the answer anyway.
Hope this helps.